# Can Java compiler avoid argument expression evaluation of Log4j argument

Tags: java, optimization, log4j

I'm trying to trace an expression to Log4j.

Assuming the evaluation of this expression is expensive, and does not produce any side-effects, is Java smart enough to prevent the overhead of the expression computation in WARN mode?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it. Expensive or not logging statements don't seem like they'd get executed often enough to count as hotspots. (That's assuming the JVM is capable of doing this sort of data flow analysis in the first place, seeing as whether the expression can be eliminated or not depends on the value of mutable integer in a different class altogether.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This exactly why you have lot of `if(logger.isXXXEnabled())` checks scattered across code base. I suggest you shift to slf4j which avoids this evaluation (provided you use it properly i.e. [parameterized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance)).

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, what you mean. If understood corrctly, what you mean, the answer is: No

```
log.trace("this log" + something() + " is expensive");
```

If you don't want this log statement to bee calculated, you'll need to wrapo the code:

```
if(log.isTraceEnabled()) log.trace("this log" + something() + " is expensive");
```